# How can I scroll till specific object visible in Squish Tests (QT application)?

Tags: qml, qt5, squish

I want to scroll to a specific object till it is visible in squish tests. This scroll is a horizontal one. I'm using a QT application. Currently I'm using `mouseDrag` method to do that. But it doesn't move to the correct position. I need to move it very consistently. I'm using QML to create those QT UI's. Help will be appreciated

Comment: please provide [mcve] instead of explaing your code.

Comment: Since timing of replay can differ, the most consistent solution might be to use the respective Qt API from the Squish test script directly. However, Qt consists of various technologies (Qt Widgets, QtQuick/QML, QGraphicsView, Web View, etc.), and the solution would likely need to be targeted at the specific Qt technology in use, so you probably need to share more details. (Also your mandatory support contract with the vendor gives you access to their technical support, and you should consider tapping into that.)